# Infopath Form Print as PDF and Send it via e-mail

Tags: pdf, sharepoint-2007, moss, infopath, infopath-2007

We have a process where users would create an Infopath Form (Web Based) to submit requests. Based on the request an approval workflow is triggered and the Infopath form is stored in a Form Library. 
Based on the status of the approval, we want to Convert the Infopath form into a PDF and send it via e-mail as an attachment. (Infopath is not available with all users. Certain e-mail receipients will not have access to SharePoint Form library where the Infopath form is stored, no use by sharing the link to the form)

Any pointers of creating a Designer/Custom workflow to convert the Infopath form into PDF and send it across to a mail address as an attachment.

MOSS2007 and Infopath 2007.

Regards
HItesh V